# SSIS(Kingswaysoft):Two different metadata sources into single destination

Tags: ssis, kingswaysoft

Is it possible to have flatfile and JSON source as inputs to a JSON destination?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?   Is there something you tried to do that resulted in an error?

Comment: Just want to know what is the dataflow component that can be used to merge them together

Answer (score 2):

I would like to clarify, using our JSON Merge or JSON Destination component (I work for KingswaySoft), we can merge the results from more than one SSIS inputs. You don't need to pre-merge using a Merge Join component or something in that nature. There is a reason that we call the component a JSON **Merge** component. :)

I hope this makes sense, please let me know if you need any further assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two sources merged side-by-side, use the  the Merge Join Component to merge the two sources into one before reaching the destination.

If you want them merged vertically, use the Union All component.

Comment: Is it gonna work for components with different metadata....because in my case it is JSON src and faltfile??

Comment: Depends on what the data is, and what you want the final result to look like.